# What is the equivalent of the MouseLeave routed event in Style.Triggers?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to animate a canvas opacity on mouse enter, but i cannot find the equivalent event to animate when a mouse leaves the canvas.

Comment: Perhaps a Trigger on the IsMouseOver property.

Comment: Notice the exitactions https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-animations-enteractions-exitactions/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple reproducible example with mouse animation enter/leave on a canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue">
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadeout"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadein">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0.1" To="1.0" Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="fadein"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="fadeout">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.1" Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```